# Toner leaking onto drum?

Tags: printer, laser-printer, toner

So I have a Dell 3130n where the black toner cartridge is possibly leaking.  The drum gets the 2 streaks at the margin, which is pretty common (we have several such printers at the office).  However, this is the first time that wiping the drum off with a microfibre cloth has not improved the situation, usually I can turn through the whole thing, wiping as I turn, and when I get to where I started it is all clean with no new spillage.  However I just turn and turn infinitely and there is always more on the drum.  I am assuming that it is leaking, is there any way I can confirm this and possibly fix it?  The toner was changed v recently and I'd rather not have to replace it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've noticed this happening with defective toner cartridges in the past. If you have another toner of the same model, try swapping it out. This usually fixes the problem of excessive toner dump for me.

Comment: Josh R. is correct, if the drum is bad, the only useful solution is to replace the toner cartridge.

Comment: Yes, this was what I did, I was just hoping there was a way to use the full but leaking one, but I guess my company got robbed for $95.  Oh well, that's why I do all my personal printing at a print shop, I know I'm only going to pay $.05 per page, instead of $50!

Answer (score -2):

toner leak is covered by the manufacturer, Clean toner out of printer! it conducts electric and can ruin printers. check with your service manual.

Comment: Toner is basically colored plastic.  It is attracted to, and held by, charged areas on the page because it does not conduct electricity.